# simulating a photo diode response- how to make use of pulsating current sources

Tags: current-source, photodiode, laser

Currently my photo diode is exposed to pulsed laser with

Pulse width           : 10ns < tw  < 150ns

Pulse repetition rate : 1Hz  < PRF < 70Khz

Expected peak current : 50mA

so when i try to design my circuits usually i use a current source for photo diode and a parallel capacitance and a shunt resistance, but how to simulate this kind of waveforms where the current will be present for 10ns and then off its like a switching current source but with different time and repetition rate

has any one tried to simulate a response like this, this kind of response may also be seen in photo diodes which are exposed to RC-5 signals from a IR LED of a TV remote

**EDIT**:
when i see different simulators all have a similar pulsating current sources,

TINA Current Generator:

[image]

NI Current Generator

[image]

ADISimPE Current Generator

[image]

but what exactly is the voltage source doing here ? , why are they introducing voltage source into current source ?, if suppose i want to use it for my purpose how should i play with it ?, i was not able to properly see my TIA behavior because of this confusion when i reduce the AC voltage of a current source i see my TIA properly functioning , any way this is just a try but i clearly dont know, how to use these pulsating sources as photo diode response

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea - you could try using the propagation delay through a logic gate to form very narrow pulses. By adding more gates you can increase the width of the pulse.

A simple (variable) pulse generator (e.g. a 555 astable) could be used to alter pulse rate. The circuit works on the rising edge only.

[image]

Comment: i am speaking analog pulse response not digital, the photo diode gives a current only response, so i need a current source, the narrow pulses can be generated from various sources in simulators, they are out of my interest

Answer (score 0):

> has any one tried to simulate a response like this

[image]

You set the current source to produce the waveform you want i.e. 2ns rise time, 10ns steady then 10ns fall time. All sims will allow this to be cycled at some repetition rate.

Comment: but i observed these current sources to be called pulsed current sources, for example the TINA simulator i am using, does have a pulsating current source, but it has option to select voltage of pulse ! how to understand this ?

Comment: I expect Tina just needs a little understanding and patience. Try it and see what happens. It's not like you will destroy valuable chips.

Comment: A normal current source will (or can) produce an infinite open circuit voltage to drive the current into an open circuit. maybe the voltage parameter is just putting a cap on this. BTW did you eventually understand about noise gain mentioned in my answer to your TIA question?

Comment: when i try to use it according to my need, what will be best way to do , should i have to put maximum voltage,  i did not see it working as per my requirement, i will post the observations please wait

Comment: dear can you please clear some doubts on current sources, find the edit

Comment: I've never used Tina but I urge you to contact a user group who can probably tell you.

Comment: put TINA aside, can you just suggest any simulator which has a pulsating current source with out any voltage input parameters to be given

Comment: I use micro-cap but I couldn't see what voltage parameters you meant in any of the pictures - you need to be clearer.

Comment: ! you can clearly see in all three pictures, 1stone TINA in signal editor gives the option of amplitude, and in 2nd one you can see AC analysis magnitude and 3rd one you can see vertical limit in volts !

Comment: No I cannot see what you mean try editing the pictures BUT this is all largely irrelevant because I don't know how to advise you other than to find a user of tina and ask them. I've explained how to model a photodiode and that was the question.